# Force page to reload from server instead of load the cached version

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have webpage A. The user clicks on a form to submit data, and it takes him to webpage B. When he clicks the back button, I need webpage A to be refreshed from the server, rather that loaded from cache. I have this: `<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">` but it doesnt seem to work. I have also tried setting a variable on page B (session variable via php) and then check for it on page A and refresh (or not) according to its existence. This doest seem to work either. The basic code for that is: 
Page A:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['reloadPage'])) {
unset($_SESSION['reloadPage']);
echo'
<script>
window.location.replace("/****/****/*****.php");
</script>
';
}
?>
```

And on page B:

```
$_SESSION['reloadPage'] = 1;
```

With the PHP solution, it simply keeps trying to refresh the page in a never ending loop. Something in my logic missing? Is this the right way to go about it?

**EDIT**
Upon further investigation, when you tell the browser to not cache the page, does that force a full *server side* refresh as well? That's what I need. A full server side refresh of the page.

Comment: Is they a online version we can see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK try this instead:

```
<?php
    if(!session_id()) {
        @session_start();   
    }
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 

    if(isset($_SESSION['form_submitted'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['form_submitted']);
        header('Location: ?' . uniqid());
        #header('Refresh: 0');
    }
?>
```

You will need to set $_SESSION['form_submitted'] = true on page 2.

Comment: Not working as hoped. But upon thinking about it further, it seems as though its not caching the page... BUT, it isn't refreshing server side from what I can tell.

Comment: Is they an online version we can look at?

Comment: I will see if I can get something public.

Comment: Got it working - this worked. I didnt work the first time, because I forgot I had some other code I was testing that was giving me fits. Once I remembered that was there and deleted it, it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try with all three:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"> <!-- tells browser not to cache -->
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> <!-- says that the cache expires 'now' -->
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> <!-- says not to use cached stuff, if there is any -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['reloadPage'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['reloadPage']);
           //no outputting code above header
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        header("Location: http://www.mypage.com/");
    }
?>
```

Comment: It said too many redirects... although I believe this is the best solution so far. It seems like it is not correctly unsetting the reloadPage variable.

Comment: It could be that the header is already sent, this will happen if there is any outputting code before the header, like any HTML or echo/print, or anything else that gets outputted to the document, the header should be the first thing that is sent. This usually gives a "header already sent" error, so it could also be the session variable that is not unset, and that it keeps on in a loop, try fiddling around a little, or check the variable for a certain value, and set it to null instead of unsetting it etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question and already have the answer (that not refreshing from the server). So I would like to share a solution using jQuery.

```
$('#back-button').click(function(){
   setTimeout(location.reload(true), 1000);
});
```

Explanation:
As you click the back button, the `setTimeout` will triggered after 1 second (1000 milliseconds). Then, the page will reload from the server as the parameter inside the `reload` is `true`.

If you put `true` inside the `reload` it will reload from the server while if you put `false` it will reload from the cache. Source [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript should be...

```
window.location = "/****/****/*****.php"
```

I think that should fix your loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['reloadPage'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['reloadPage']);
  echo'
  <script>
  window.location.replace("/****/****/*****.php");
  </script>
  ';
}
?>
```