# PHP Page content loads from cache when loading same page multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I am displaying shopping cart products by reading session variables.

If a product is added in a **page1** , I am setting session array variable. after navigating to 
**page2** i am loading the session content to display the product in shopping cart in **page2**.

Then if i add any product in **page2** then going to **page1** , the **page1** is not showing refreshed content, instead it takes content from page1 cache.

> But when i do F5 or CTRL+F5, it works fine...

I want the page **not** to load from cache everytime when i visit even if it is same page.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php 
    echo "<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {";
    echo "add1('".$session_variable."')";
    echo "});</script>";
?>
<script>
add1(item)
{
document.getElementById('ItemName').value=item;
}
<script>
```

**EDIT:** I navigate from Page 1 to Page2 using **onclick event** as below..

```
<a onclick="window.location='page2.php'" style="text-decoration:none">Page2</a><br>
<a onclick="window.location='page1.php'" style="text-decoration:none">Page1</a><br>
```

I added following lines, But no use.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache,must-revalidate">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

Comment: Try this: <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">

Comment: It appears to me that this ain't a cache related problem. Show us how do you assignate your session variable.

Comment: @Su4p : then how it works when i do F5 ?

Comment: @Danny session and cache don't interact with each other. If you do F5 or even ctrl+F5 it shouldn't alter session variable.

Comment: @logan that's what I want to know. That's why I want to see how do you assignate your session.

Comment: Could you paste your code? How are you going to page1? By back button?

Comment: Maybe your doing an `back navigate` instead of an clean navigate to page1? Because if you go 'back', an cached version will be loaded...

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger : i have pasted my code

Comment: @Mathlight : I am clicking the page1 link in page2; no back button

Comment: @logan That code does not explain how your session variables is getting set.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger : storing session variable is happening through an ajax call.. its working fine.. there is no doubt with that as it displays product in in Page1 when i clicked product and in page2; if anything added in page2 shows the product in page2 but not showing in page1

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132446/force-page-to-reload-from-server-instead-of-load-the-cached-version) is a similar page, hope that is helpful.

Comment: How do you navigate back to back one, do you have a url that is clicked that navs back or do you use window.history.back()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you navigate back to back one, do you have a url that is clicked that navs back or do you use window.history.back()?

If you are using javascript to nav back then that may be the issue.  When navigating back to page 1 use a url with a cache break at the end of it like so

```
window.location.href = "/page1.php?cb=" + Math.random();
```

Comment: i navigate page using onclick event.. please see my updated question with EDIT

Comment: what do you mean by `+ Math.random();`

Comment: That is just a cache breaker, if the page is being loaded from cache that random at the end will make it download a fresh page from the server

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities:

1. You're developing a single page application, then you should update the contents of "page" 1 manually
2. You're using the javascript command "history.go(-1);" to navigate back to page 1, if this is the case, i suggest the using of a regular link
3. You are, someway, not setting the session correctly
4. You are not really using sessions

Comment: its not single page application. i explained the problem correctly. if i dont set session correctly, then how is it working when i do CTRL + F5 ?

Comment: are you using javascript to go back to page 1?

Comment: try to use a regular link instead: <a href="page1.php">Page1</a>

Comment: you will not need those random numbers thing, the browser is smart enough to load the contents correctly. The random number thing is useful in applications such as calendars (content from javascript, ajax, etc...), and this is not your case

Comment: i wanted to use onclick., so random number concept will work right ?

Comment: why using javascript to do something a link natively does??? This just makes thing complicated. And yes, the random number will work anyway, but it is not necessary

Comment: i am using css menu style., so onclick is required.. javascript will cause any problem ?

Comment: Use a regular link. It will not interfere on your css

Comment: thats fine andre & i agree., can you explain, is there any problem or disadvantage using javascript ?  i will add Math.random();

Answer (score 0):

redirect / or Intercept the f5 key / to recall the page with a parameter, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dfocus  = $("input");
dfocus.keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 116 ) { //f5
        document.location.href="mypage.php?id="+Math.random(); // this may enforce to reload the page
    }
...
```

then you will enforce to load the page. (Same logic than img src with cache)

Comment: this will refresh the page after loading the page... i want it to happen while first load itself

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding 
`<?php echo "<!--" . rand(0,9999999) . "-->"; ?>` in your code on index page.

Then please try the procedure above again and tell me the results.

And also try adding

```
<?php
    if(!session_id()) {
        @session_start();   
    }
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 

    if(isset($_SESSION['form_submitted'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['form_submitted']);
        header('Location: ?' . uniqid());
        #header('Refresh: 0');
    }
?>
```

Comment: `"; ?> ` why do you want to me to add ? where to add this ? all syntax are correct in my code

Comment: @logan , sorry the code didn't show properly here, but I formated it and it shows correctly now.

Comment: @logan are you building this on top of any php frameworks, if not, are  you using any caching classes?

Answer (score 0):

By default window.location uses assign() to change the location, usually this is good enough but I think you could use replace() instead and get the desire results. Something like this:
window.location.replace('page1.php')